# Modifying RDD flow definition from streaming context at runtime

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

I have e.g. an on RDD from a streaming context on which I perform a `map`, `filter` and `count`, and let my system run for a while.

Based on certain input, I would like to completely modify this processing at runtime to be e.g. `map`, `map` ,`flatMap`.

How can I replace the entire processing flow at runtime after the initial one has been materialized and is running?
Do I need to stop the context and restart it or are there other runtime option?